# Perl substitution using string that contains a dollar sign on windows

Tags: windows, regex, perl, string

I'm using perl on windows and am trying to do a one liner using perl to substitute a placeholder in a file using a windows variable that contains a dollar sign. Does anyone know what the correct usage is to make it work with the dollar sign. I've tried various ways and can't seem to get it to work.

For example, I have a properties file that has a  token in it (!MYPASSWORD!) that I'm trying to replace like:

```
somevalue="!MYPASSWORD!"
```

I have a batch file that looks up a variable say called NEWPASSWORD that contains the password $abc12345$ and I want to use perl substitution to replace the value like the following. Note I may not always know where the $ signs are so I cant escape them. For example another password may be abc$124$563:

```
echo %NEWPASSWORD%   <-- this would contain $abc12345$
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/!MYPASSWORD!/%NEWPASSWORD%/g" a.properties
```

When its done I want a.properties to be :

```
somevalue="$abc12345$"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see what your actual question is here? Can you give an example of something that isn't working and what you want it to do? That is, *provide code*.

Comment: the following is the code:

echo %NEWPASSWORD%   <-- this would contain $abc12345$
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/!MYPASSWORD!/%NEWPASSWORD%/g" a.properties

if new password variable contains $abc12345$ and i run the substitution it doesn't work

Answer (score 12):

Use `'` as regexp delimeter symbol. It will disable all variable substitution:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s'!MYPASSWORD!'%NEWPASSWORD%'g" a.properties
```

Comment: Nice DWIMing, Ivan. An alternative would be to not let the shell fill in the value of the environmental variable: `s/!MYPASSWORD!/$ENV{NEWPASSWORD}/g`

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are getting password from user input. why not just do that in Perl without having to go through batch since you are already using Perl? Its easier. you can then use modules like [Term::Inkey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::InKey) to mask password and stuff.

Comment: Surely, you are joking?  There is no way that Perl's error handling and flow control are up to the task.  A heavy duty language like DOS batch is much more appropriate for tasks like this.

Comment: Ok, all joking aside, using a more powerful language, like Perl, will make these sorts of scripts much easier to maintain and reuse.

Comment: you must be kidding too. Perl is so much more powerful than batch. In terms of error handling in batch, have you ever seen better ones other than %errorlevel% ?

Answer (score -2):

simply use escape before dollar, like that :

```
\$
```